# Create a ring on the surface of a sphere in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have a sphere in threejs, and I'd like a ring to animate over the top of it.

I have the following progress:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/zYRdQOw/2919f1a1bdcd2643390efc33bd4b73c9?editors=0010

In the animate function, I call:

```
const scale = Math.cos((circlePos / this.globeRadius) * Math.PI * 0.5);
console.log(scale);
this.ring.scale.set(scale, scale, 1);
```

My understanding is that the `sin` and `cos` functions are exactly what I need to work out how far around the circle the ring has gotten to. However, the animation actually shows the ring fall inside the sphere, before eventually hitting the 0 scale at the outside of the sphere.

Ideally, I'd also like to just be changing the radius of the sphere but I cannot work out how to do that either, so I think it may be an issue of using the `scale` function.

How can I keep the ring on the surface of the sphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. Consider this:

You have a right triangle whose bases are your *x* and *y*, with a hypotenuse of *r = globeRadius*. So by Pythagoras' theorem, we have:

*x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>*.

So if we solve for the height, *y*, we get:

*y = √(r<sup>2</sup> - x<sup>2</sup>)*.

Thus, in your code, you could write it e.g. like this:

```
const scale = Math.sqrt(this.globeRadius * this.globeRadius - circlePos * circlePos);
```

However, this is the scale in terms of world units, not relative to the objects. So for this to work, you need to either divide by your radius again, or just initialise your ring with radius 1:

```
this.ringGeometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(1, 1.03, 32);
```

Here I gave it an arbitrary ring width of 0.03 - you may of course adjust it to your own needs.